# Running multiple AJAX functions through onclick event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I feel as if this issue is pretty simple, so I may be overlooking something pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to find the solution on Facebook. Basically I have two AJAX functions that interface with PHP scripts through the `onClick` event. Here is how I am laying out the HTML:

```
onClick = "previousMonth(this.id); monthDisplay_previous(this.id)"
```

Currently, it is displaying the output from `previousMonth(this.id)`.  But if I reverse the function calls and set it up as:

```
onClick = "monthDisplay_previous(this.id); previousMonth(this.id)"
```

then it only displays the output from `monthDisplay_previous(this.id)` -- it just won't run them both. In addition, they both interface with different PHP scripts. I feel like this is enough information to go off of, but if you want me to post more code I will, reluctantly. Any ideas?

Comment: not enough detail. what do these two functions do? if monthDisplay does a redirect and moves the browser to a different page, it would be impossible for previousMonth to ever do anything.

Comment: @MarcB they dont redirect, they change text on the page bassed off of a two different php scripts

Comment: @Nick where you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they can run in parallel, you might try somethign like this

```
var someFunction = function(that_id) {
  previousMonth(that_id);
  monthDisplay_previous(that_id);
}

onClick = "someFunction(this.id);"
```

Comment: still nothing.. i suppose if i stare at it long enough something will come to me. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping both of your functions into another one.

```
onClick = function(){ previousMonth(this.id); monthDisplay_previous(this.id); }
```

Comment: Ops, sorry about that. Well, I made a simple code using jquery that might help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/uQVW7/